# trying to read a delimited text file from resources - but it wont run

Tags: vb.net, file

I'm having a problem where instead of reading a text file from the location string, I changed it to read the text file from the resource location and it breaks my program.  I've also used the insert snippet method to get most of this code, so it is safe to say I don't know what is going on.  Could some one please help?

```
   'reads the text out of a delimited text file and puts the words and hints into to separate arrays
   ' this works and made the program run
   ' Dim filename As String = Application.StartupPath + "\ProggramingList.txt"
    'this dosnt work and brings back a Illegal characters in path error.
    dim filename as string = My.Resources.ProggramingList
    Dim fields As String()
    'my text files are delimited
    Dim delimiter As String = ","
    Using parser As New TextFieldParser(filename)
        parser.SetDelimiters(delimiter)
        While Not parser.EndOfData
            ' Read in the fields for the current line
            fields = parser.ReadFields()
            ' Add code here to use data in fields variable.

            'put the result into two arrays (the fields are the arrays im talking about). one holds the words, and one holds the corresponding hint
            Programingwords(counter) = Strings.UCase(fields(0))
            counter += 1
            'this is where the hint is at
            Programingwords(counter) = (fields(1))
            counter += 1
        End While
    End Using
```

the error

ex.ToString()
"System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path)
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePathFast(String path, Boolean fullCheck)
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.NormalizePath(String Path)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser.ValidatePath(String path)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser.InitializeFromPath(String path, Encoding defaultEncoding, Boolean detectEncoding)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser..ctor(String path)
   at HangMan.Form1.GetWords() in I:\vb\HangMan\HangMan\Form1.vb:line 274"  String

Comment: Can you post where `My.Resources.GamesList` is set?

Comment: im guessing the resource folder? i just added the text files to the  programs resources. the only reason im doing this is so that my program can be run from .exe file.

Comment: sorry if the fact that my uncommented code was causing confusion. but both files should be named proggramingList

Comment: "it messes up my program"? Are you a child? In what way does it "it messes up my program"? Is there an exception? Then post the complete exception (ex.ToString(), not ex.Message).

Comment: sorry for the grammar, is that the exception information you wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TextFieldParser constructor you use expects the name of a file.  Instead, it gets the contents of the file.  That goes Kaboom, the file content is not a valid path to a file.  You'll need to the constructor that takes a Stream and use the StringReader class to provide the stream.  For example:

```
Dim fields As String()
Dim delimiter As String = ","
Dim fileContent As String = My.Resources.ProggramingList
Dim stringStream as New System.IO.StringReader(fileContent)
Using parser As New TextFieldParser(stringStream)
  REM etc...
End Using
```

This is a bit wasteful of memory but not an issue if the text is less than a megabyte or so.  If it is more then you shouldn't put it in a resource.

Comment: Thank you very much! thanks for explaining to me what was going on too. works just like it should! you are the man!

Comment: i'm not ranked high enough to make it helpful. sorry, i did try :(

Comment: thanks, i'll make sure i come back to give it, you've helped me so much

Answer (score 0):

When you debug this code, what is the value of the variable filename after you read it from My.Resources.GamesList? Is it a valid string, does it point to you're file?

Comment: file name is what it should be.  A very long string.  If you need the value i can post it